# Why does 'monit' not monitor my process?

Tags: macos, monit

In my `.monitrc` I have

```
check process macupdate
    matching "MacUpdate *"
    if uptime > 10 minutes then exec "/Users/Rax/Library/Automation/Shell/monit_macupdate"
```

and I can confirm that

```
monit procmatch "MacUpdate *"
```

finds a running process

```
/Applications/MacUpdate Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/MacUpdate Desktop
```

but `monit status` reports that `macupdate` is "Not monitored".

Why does 'monit' not monitor my process?

Answer (score 0):

Your matching will not work with monit.

Try the below:

check process macupdate
    matching MacUpdate
    if uptime > 10 minutes then exec "/Users/Rax/Library/Automation/Shell/monit_macupdate"

Regards
Salman